# How do I subscribe to a bootstrapped button's Click event using jQuery to toggle a DIV's visibility?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have two buttons and I have two DIVs. I want to toggle the visibility of two DIVs (dvShowWithdrawals, dvHideWithdrawals) each time I press any one of two buttons (btnShowWithdrawals, btnHideWithdrawals), but I need your help to make it work!

Below is the code I thought would toggle the visibility of my DIVs. I thought this would bring functions e and f to subscribe to the 'click' event of my two buttons. The buttons in effect are visibility togglers for those DIVs, but the code doesn't appear to be invoked when I click these buttons.

What's interesting is that both buttons are already successfully bootstrapped (using data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dvMyStuff") to perform an accordion-like effect on a third DIV (dvMyStuff). That does work.

Here's how I attempt to subscribe to the buttons' click events:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnShowWithdrawals').on('click',
        function(e) {

            $('#dvShowWithdrawals').toggle();
            $('#dvHideWithdrawals').toggle();

        });

    $('#btnHideWithdrawals').on('click',
        function(f) {

            $('#dvShowWithdrawals').toggle();
            $('#dvHideWithdrawals').toggle();

        });
</script>
```

The two DIVs actually encapsulate the two buttons whose click event I am subscribing to above. Here are the buttons themselves:

```
<div id="dvShowWithdrawals" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowWithdrawals" runat="server" Visible="True" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dvMyStuff">
        <i id="iShowWithdrawals" class="fa fa-plus-square-o" style="font-size: 40px;" title="Show my stuff"></i>
    </asp:LinkButton>
</div>    
<div id="dvHideWithdrawals" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnHideWithdrawals" runat="server" Visible="True" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dvMyStuff">
        <i id="iHideWithdrawals" class="fa fa-minus-square-o" style="font-size: 40px;" title="Hide my stuff"></i>
    </asp:LinkButton>       
</div>
```

The buttons do successfully hide and show my stuff on the third DIV with an accordion roll up/down effect:

```
<div id="dvMyStuff" class="collapse"> 
    my stuff
</div>
```

The problem is that the buttons are not hiding/showing the first two DIVs that encapsulate them. Help, please!

Comment: Try wrapping the jQuery inside a `$(document).ready(function(){....})`.

Comment: I wrapped it. Nothing. When I click on my custom btnShowWithdrawals button, my browser's developer tools still won't stop at any breakpoint I place within those functions. They don't seem to be getting invoked.

Comment: Not having the `$(document).ready(` is a problem, just may not be the only problem.  Leave that in but then also change the `ID` to lowercase and take out the `e` and `f` in the functions.  I don't think any of those is your real issue but it should be done anyways.

Comment: Changed ID to lowercase id on the buttons. Left your $(document).ready( in there. Took out the e and f in the functions. I wish I had good news!

Comment: Replace your javascript snipet with the following: `$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#btnShowWithdrawals').on('click',function() 
 {
  $('#dvShowWithdrawals').toggle();
  $('#dvHideWithdrawals').toggle();
 });

    $('#btnHideWithdrawals').on('click', function()
 {
  $('#dvShowWithdrawals').toggle();
  $('#dvHideWithdrawals').toggle();
 });
 console.log('loaded!!!');
});`  Clear cache and reload the page.  Make sure you see the `loaded!!!` in the console.  Then try it.  Are there any errors on the page?

Comment: I went with a different solution earlier, but I wanted to see if your latest idea worked and tried it. It's actually just the adaptation to my code that you suggested earlier (to remove the e and f from the functions). It failed but after tinkering a little, I got it to work also by setting the attribute style="display: none;" and  on the DIV labeled dvHideWithdrawals, and also setting ClientIDMode="Static" up at the top on the page directive. So, this is a viable alternative solution.

Comment: Glad you got it working!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ultimately worked. I want to give partial credit to nurdyguy for suggesting I wrap everything around a $(document).ready block. I'd also give credit to J.R., another friend who brainstormed some new ideas with me. First off, we changed the method used to hide/show the DIVs from within the event-handling functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnShowWithdrawals').on('click',
            function () {
                $('#dvShowWithdrawals').hide();
                $('#dvHideWithdrawals').show();
            });

        $('#btnHideWithdrawals').on('click',
            function () {
                $('#dvShowWithdrawals').show();
                $('#dvHideWithdrawals').hide();
            });
    });

</script>
```

Then, on the DIVs themselves we made one change. We added the attribute style="display: none;" only to dvHideWithdrawals:

```
<div id="dvShowWithdrawals" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowWithdrawals" runat="server" Visible="True" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dvMyStuff">
        <i id="iShowWithdrawals" class="fa fa-plus-square-o" style="font-size: 40px;" title="Show my stuff"></i>
    </asp:LinkButton>
</div>    
<div id="dvHideWithdrawals" runat="server" style="display: none;">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnHideWithdrawals" runat="server" Visible="True" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dvMyStuff">
        <i id="iHideWithdrawals" class="fa fa-minus-square-o" style="font-size: 40px;" title="Hide my stuff"></i>
    </asp:LinkButton>       
</div>
```

Separately, something new we did was to also set ClientIDMode="Static" on the page directive at the top of the markup file:

```
<%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="True" ClientIDMode="Static" CodeBehind="WeDidIt.ascx.cs" Inherits="WeDidIt" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5"%>
```

Voila! My first two DIVs are now hiding/showing as they should, and my third DIV continues to roll up/down like an accordion (as effected by bootstrap).